# Dynamic query to select columns if column matches other cell criteria

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I am trying to build a Query to sort through different staff training reports. I am able to display all "Completed" certifications from staff, however, I would also like the query to be dynamic, and only display data, if it matches the name, entered into the "search key" cell so that individual staff can be viewed.

I've tried using this formula,

```
=query(Data!A1:E50,select A,B,C,D,E where E="Completed" and A='"&$B$2&"',0")")
```

however, it returns `#ERROR!`. In this case, B2 would be the search box where you can select the Staff's name.

Here's a link.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ePKb2pg3QJeCmw5bf-4Rgg67PGLV7PARKCko4P_uTKQ/edit#gid=707448770

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

correct syntax would be:

```
=QUERY(Data!A1:E19, "select A,B,C,D,E where E='Completed' and A='"&$B$1&"'", 0)
```

[image: 0]

---

for caps insensitive search it would be:

```
=QUERY(Data!A1:E19, "select A,B,C,D,E where E='Completed' and lower(A)='"&LOWER(B1)&"'", 0)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you very much! 
More score is too low but I very much appreciate your help.